# Jquery Console Error - Cannot read property 'call' of undefined

Tags: jquery

I am getting a warning for a function that removes the in class from essentially tabs like an accordion so that only one can be on at a time (if it contains in then it opens, if another tab is opened the already open shuts, if the tab thats open is clicked it shuts).

```
function removeClassIn() {
$('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').click(function(){ 

     if ( $( this ).next().hasClass( "in" ) ) {

       $('.af-wrapper').each().removeClass( "in" );

    }

$('div[data-toggle="collapse"]').each(function(){ 
$(this).next().removeClass('in'); 
}) 
}); 


}
```

The error warning is Cannot read property 'call' of undefined. The error is only shown when the same tab is clicked as in to open and close.

The function is doing what I want it to but can this error cause other issues? And any idea where the call is missing from?

- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
- at Function.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
- at n.fn.init.each (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
- at HTMLDivElement. (VM1379 x:76) <- this is my function
  removeClassIn();
- at HTMLDivElement.dispatch (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)
- at HTMLDivElement.r.handle (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:3)

Comment: You're completely misunderstanding `.each()`.

Comment: Your code does not show any reference to `.call()`. Which line are you getting the error on? Please post the stack trace.

Comment: @obsidianAge I've edited question, is that what you mean by stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks I'm a beginner at jquery, is what I'm doing with .each() causing this do you think?

Comment: Yes; `each()` takes a parameter.  See the documentation.

Comment: @SLaks, I see. Thanks for that I've just had a look but I'm unsure what parameters could be given to my example though? Could you help me?

Comment: That's because you don't actually want to call `.each()`.  You should read the documentation for the functions you use and figure out which ones you want.

Comment: @SLaks Could you help if you know the answer? I see no other function that suits what I want to do other than each?

Comment: Call `removeClass()` directly

Comment: Thanks alot for getting back to me @SLaks, Do you mean like this? $('.af-wrapper').removeClass( "in" );? This solves my error anyway but doesn't work the same as it did. If a tab is open and then another tab is clicked then the previously open one closes correctly, but clicking the already open tab to almost flick open and shut open and shut doesn't shut itself. Or did you mean something different entirely?

Comment: Then you need to to debug your code and make it do what you want.  You probably want to exclude an element.